# __func__ and __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ not always expanded

Tags: c, gcc, macros, g++

I have a log library that uses a macro to trace a message. This macro makes use of predefined macros like `__func__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` to indicate in which function/method the message was logged.

The macro of my log library is defined in the main header of my log library, outside any function.

For some reason, the preprocessed code contains `__func__` (or `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` if i'm using this one) litterally, just like if these predefined macros didn't exist. But i know they DO exist because if i'm using them without using my lib's trace macro, they work !

Here is my libs macro :

```
#if _MSC_VER >= 1400 // If >= VS2005

    #define _TRACE_FUNC_SIGNATURE __FUNCSIG__

#elif defined(__ANDROID__) || defined( __GNUC__ ) && defined( __cplusplus ) // If G++ and/or Android NDK

    #define _TRACE_FUNC_SIGNATURE __func__

#else
    #error // Unsupported compiler
#endif

// Forces the reprocessing of x to properly expand __VA_ARGS__ when using MSVC compiler
#define _TRACE_REPROCESS( x ) x


#define _TRACE_X( _methodName_, _logCatPtr_, ... ) \
    do { \
        ::dbg::LogCategory * const _catPtrVal_ = (::dbg::LogCategory *)(_logCatPtr_); \
        if( NULL != _catPtrVal_ && _catPtrVal_->IsEnabled() ) \
        { \
            _TRACE_REPROCESS( _catPtrVal_->_methodName_( _TRACE_FUNC_SIGNATURE " - " __VA_ARGS__ ); ) \
        } \
    } while( false )


#define TRACE_E( _logCatPtr_, ... ) _TRACE_X( Error, _logCatPtr_, __VA_ARGS__ )
#define TRACE_W( _logCatPtr_, ... ) _TRACE_X( Warning, _logCatPtr_, __VA_ARGS__ )
#define TRACE_I( _logCatPtr_, ... ) _TRACE_X( Info, _logCatPtr_, __VA_ARGS__ )
```

I know that these macros have no reason to be defined outside a function, but since i'm only using my trace macro inside functions/methods, then it should be defined there !

I'm using the default Android NDK compiler provided with eclipse, which as I read is some kind of extended G++.

**EDIT** : If I replace `__func__` by an actual string litteral, it works, no syntax error. This lets me think that `__func__` is definately not defined when used in my macro.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Unfortunately i'm having the same result.

Comment: I've taken a look at the preprocessed code where there is `__func__ " - " ...` This gives me an error since a variable can't just be followed by a string litteral like this. If `__func__` was a macro, it would have expanded to a string litteral and the compiler would have prepended it to `" - "`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In some implementations, `__func__` is a variable, not a macro ([at least in gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html)). So, you cannot use it as if it were a string literal.

So, this :

```
_TRACE_REPROCESS( _catPtrVal_->_methodName_( _TRACE_FUNC_SIGNATURE " - " __VA_ARGS__ ); )
```

will have to be written differently. I don't know how `_catPtrVal_->_methodName_` is implemented, but if it can take multiple parameters, then something like this will probably do the trick :

```
_TRACE_REPROCESS( _catPtrVal_->_methodName_( _TRACE_FUNC_SIGNATURE, " - " __VA_ARGS__ ); )
```

If not, then you'll have to use some other way of concatenating `__func__` with the rest of the log line (using a [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) eg.).

### More details

The C standard specifies `__func__` like this :

> The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
>   immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration
>
> `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";`
>
> appeared, where *function-name* is the name of the lexically-enclosing function.

Ie. it leaves it up to the implementation whether to provide it as a variable, or a macro (as long as it behaves as if it were defined as shown above).

As an example, [gcc provides it as a variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Function-Names.html), and [MSVC provides it as a macro](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0084kay.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I thought it was a macro seeing the `__` and since `__FUNCSIG__` is a macro on MSVC. It would have been handy if it was a macro as i could simply concatenate it at compile-time.

Comment: @Virus721 : unfortunately, the C standard only requires that : "The identifier `__func__` shall be implicitly declared by the translator as if,
immediately following the opening brace of each function definition, the declaration `static const char __func__[] = "function-name";` appeared.". I didn't know MSVC provided it as a macro, but you can't rely on other implementations doing the same.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I'd add my two cents - it IS possible to use the function signature in preprocessor directives, but you have to capture it first. Here's an example working up to a comparison of `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` and the preprocessor alternative.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CAT(X,Y) X ## Y

#define VAR(X) X
#define VAR_(X) VAR(X)

#define VAL(X) #X
#define VAL_(X) VAL(X)

/* Alias for constexpr cstring */
#define SZ const char*
#define CE_SZ constexpr SZ

/* Alias for assignment with appended log statement */
#define LOG(X, Y) X = Y; CE_SZ VAR_(CAT(INFO_, X)) = \
        VAL_(X) " = " VAL_(Y) " (" __FILE__ VAL_(:__LINE__) ")"

/* SZ_A has no preprocessor value */
CE_SZ SZ_A = "Value of SZ_A";

/* SZ_B only has value to the preprocessor during LOG
    (no define from inside a define, macro, etc.) */
CE_SZ LOG(SZ_B, "Value of SZ_B");

/* SZ_C has a global preprocessor name and value, but no compile time name */
#define SZ_C "Value of SZ_C"

/* SZ_D associates a compile time name with the value of SZ_C */
CE_SZ LOG(SZ_D, SZ_C);

/*
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ and __func__  don't expand to string literals, but
    to references to strings initialized by the compiler. If you capture the
    signature in a preprocessor define, it's available globally; if you pass
    it to a preprocessor macro, it's available within the scope of the macro.
    __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ depends on compiler implementation (if it's defined
    at all) - parameter names will be missing, template typenames and values
    will be enumerated, etc.
*/
#define SIG template<typename T = SZ> void test(T caller)
SIG {
    /* int main(int, const char**) */
    printf("  Called function: %s\n", caller);
    /* void test(T) [with T = const char*] */
    printf(" Current function: %s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    /* template<typename T = const char*> void test(T caller) */
    printf(" Preprocessor signature: " VAL_(SIG) "\n");
}

CE_SZ LOG(SZ_E, VAL_(SIG));

int main(int argc, const char *argv[]) {
    /* SZ_A = "Value of SZ_A" */
    printf("%s = \"%s\"\n", VAL_(SZ_A), SZ_A);

    /* SZ_B = "Value of SZ_B" (main.cpp:26) */
    printf("%s\n", INFO_SZ_B);

    /* SZ_C = "Value of SZ_C" */
    printf("%s\n", "SZ_C = " VAL_(SZ_C));

    /* SZ_D = "Value of SZ_D" (main.cpp:32) */
    printf("%s\n\n", INFO_SZ_D);

    test(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    /* SZ_E = "template..." (main.cpp:53) */
    printf("\n%s\n", INFO_SZ_E);
}
```