# C++ macro to test availability of __func__, __FUNCTION__, __PRETTY_FUNCTION__, etc

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, macros

Various modern C/C++ compilers include one or both of `__func__` / `__FUNCTION__` for purposes of logging the currently executing function. MSVC++ also includes `__FUNCSIG__` and GCC `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` as compiler-specific enhanced flavors of this functionality.

GCC defines these as *variables* rather than macros, however, so it isn't possible to test for their presence via a `#ifdef` preprocessor directive.

I'm working with a codebase that must work with C++98 and C++11 flavors of MSVC++ and GCC, and the logging facility that someone wrote erroneously tries to test for `__FUNCTION__` if `__FUNCSIG__` is not available. This check always returns false, rendering function logging support non-operational.

**Question:** Is there a good macro out there that makes a sufficient-for-my-use-cases guess at which (if any) of these features should be present, possibly by sniffing out compiler versions?

Comment: You could some `configure` approach generating a tiny header file (read about [autoconf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoconf)) at build time

Comment: `__func__` have never been a macro, it's defined by the C++ specification to be a variable.

Comment: Who suggested that `__func__` was ever a macro?

Comment: Well you seem to be wanting to use the preprocessor to check for these, and I'm just telling you that while some compilers might have the others as macros, `__func__` will never be a macro and can therefore never be tested for by the preprocessor.

Comment: `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION`.

Comment: @T.C. well that's desperately simple. It doesn't have the decorations from `__FUNCSIG__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` though.

Comment: @Quentin um, it does?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You appear to have ignored my second paragraph :(

Comment: @T.C. Thanks, I saw this in an old version of Boost but can't find it in the docs for the current version. Can you point me to docs on a current version?

Comment: It's under [Boost.Assert](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html#current_function_macro_boost_current_function_hpp).

Comment: @T.C. oh, it does indeed. The [documentation](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.utility) I've found states that it is "the same thing [as] the standardized macro `__func__`", and that one does not have decorations (nor is it a macro, come to think of it). Well, case closed :p

Comment: @T.C. Can you post your suggestion as a proper answer, with these links: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html#current_function_macro_boost_current_function_hpp and http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/boost/current_function.hpp so that you can get credit? Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That's not quite correct. `__func__` can be a variable or a macro, it's just required to behave in a certain way (see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33806001/942179)

Comment: @ElmarZander That seems to be for C not C++. From [the C++ standard in the `[dcl.fct.def.general]` section](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.general#:__func__): "The function-local predefined **variable** `__func__` is defined as ..." (emphasis mine).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay, sorry, got me... In the C standard it's "identifier `__func__`" and in C++ it's "variable `__func__`". I overlooked that bit...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

T.C. supplied this answer first, as a comment under my question, and I ended up basing my solution on it:

The header `<boost/current_function.hpp>` in Boost.Assert implements a `BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION` macro that attempts to map to a suitable "current function" facility provided by the compiler.

Documentation is here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/assert/doc/html/assert.html#current_function_macro_boost_current_function_hpp

And here is a concise reproduction of the macro for reference:

```
#if defined( BOOST_DISABLE_CURRENT_FUNCTION )
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION "(unknown)"
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || (defined(__MWERKS__) && (__MWERKS__ >= 0x3000)) || (defined(__ICC) && (__ICC >= 600)) || defined(__ghs__)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#elif defined(__DMC__) && (__DMC__ >= 0x810)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __PRETTY_FUNCTION__
#elif defined(__FUNCSIG__)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __FUNCSIG__
#elif (defined(__INTEL_COMPILER) && (__INTEL_COMPILER >= 600)) || (defined(__IBMCPP__) && (__IBMCPP__ >= 500))
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __FUNCTION__
#elif defined(__BORLANDC__) && (__BORLANDC__ >= 0x550)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __FUNC__
#elif defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && (__STDC_VERSION__ >= 199901)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __func__
#elif defined(__cplusplus) && (__cplusplus >= 201103)
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION __func__
#else
# define BOOST_CURRENT_FUNCTION "(unknown)"
#endif
```

I ended up modifying the codebase I was working with to use the Boost macro when available, and to fall back to a reasonable subset of the Boost checks otherwise (GCC > MSVC++ > C++11).

Answer (score 1):

`__func__` was specified in C99 (not C++) and gcc has provided `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` for quite a while.   However, none are actually macros, so can't be used as such.  Among other things, that means you can't test for them using `#ifdef`.

To test if you are compiling as C++, and to what standard, use `__cplusplus` which is specified in the C++ standard, and expands to values `199711L` (before C++11), `201103L` (C++11), `201402L` (C++14), and `201703L` (C++17).     The values correspond to the dates (year and month) when the standardisation committee approved the standard (e.g. `201703L` means that C++17 was approved in March 2017).    Note this is macro is only defined when compiling C++, not C.

Beyond that, to use features specific to a compiler, you need to test for the compiler that supports the features you want, not the feature itself (although some compilers/preprocessors do allow testing for particular language features, that's patchy in practice).

gcc and g++ (and other compilers that claim to support gnu C dialects) provide a number of specific macros, so you can check for them including

- `__GNUC__`, defined for the GNU C compiler (can be tested using `#ifdef`).    For gcc version `x.y.z`, `__GNUC__` expands to the value `x`;
- `__GNUC_MINOR__`, defined for the GNU C compiler (can be tested using `#ifdef`).    For gcc version `x.y.z`, `__GNUC_MINOR__` expands to the value `y`;
- `__GNUC_PATCH_LEVEL__`, defined for the GNU C compiler (can be tested using `#ifdef`).    For gcc version `x.y.z`, `__GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__` expands to the value `z`;
- `__GNUG__` - defined for the g++ compiler.

An example of how you might use the gnu-specific macros is

```
 #ifdef __GNUG__

     /*   Assume all versions of gcc that you use support __FUNCTION__ */

     /*  can use gcc's __FUNCTION__ here   */

 #endif
```

I don't know offhand which g++ versions started supporting `__FUNCTION__` and `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__`, but if you want to test for particular version of the compiler, it's easy.   For example, to test for g++ 3.2.0 or better

```
 #ifdef __GNUG__
 // test for g++ 3.2.0 or better
 #if __GNUC__ > 3 ||                            \ 
       (__GNUC__ == 3 && (__GNUC_MINOR__ > 2 || \
                   (__GNUC_MINOR__ == 2 &&      \
                    __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__ > 0))  

        // use features not introduced before g++ 3.2.0

 #endif
 #endif
```

For MSVC++, compiler-specific macros for a similar purpose include `_MSC_VER` which expands to an encoding of the major and minor versions.   For example, under MSVC++ version 17.00.51106.1,   `_MSC_VER` expands to 1700.   You can find others on MSDN.

Comment: Thanks. This is about how far I got on my own, except that apparently MSVC++ `__FUNCSIG__` is actually a macro that can be tested for directly. I ended up getting a more specific answer from Boost, as suggested by T.C. in a comment on my question.